# WinForm New instance of form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this block of code:

```
Form1 newForm = new Form1();
newForm.Show();
```

`//The rest of this code has been omitted`

more or less. Form1 is just for example purposes. My issue is that I am creating a text editor (continuation of my last question, basically) and I want to be able to have more than one copy of Form1 open at once.

This code allows me to do that, which is great, but I want to be able to close the old one and still have the newForm on the screen. Currently, if I close Form1, I say goodbye to newForm.

Is this possible? I don't want to have to just white-out all the next like Notepad does.

Comment: So you want to show at least once instance of Form1. Isn't it?

Comment: Basically, I suppose. I can open and close as many newForms as I want currently, but I can't have newForm independently open without Form1

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing your `Form1` is also the one created and passed to `Application.Run()` in your `main` method, correct?  Something like `Application.Run(new Form1());`

In that case (which is the default), you are telling the framework to exit the application when that form closes.

You probably want to change your `main` method to use the [overload of `Application.Run()` that takes an ApplicationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx), and within the app context, create your forms - then when your last form closes, you can exit the application.   The example in the link to MSDN shows a very similar case.

You could simply change main to:

```
Form1 newForm = new Form1();
newForm.Show();
Application.Run();
```

but the issue with this is that the application may not exit correctly without more housekeeping by you.

**Added:**
This is a simple example, but shows the concept.  Create a ApplicationContext class like this one:

```
public class CustomContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private readonly List<Form1> _openForms = new List<Form1>();

    public CustomContext()
    {
        CreateForm();
    }

    private void CreateForm()
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.OpenNewForm += (sender, args) =>  CreateForm();
        form.Closed += (sender, args) => FormClosed(sender as Form1);
        _openForms.Add(form);
        form.Show();
    }

    private void FormClosed(Form1 form)
    {
        _openForms.Remove(form);
        if (_openForms.Count == 0)
        {
            ExitThread();
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Program` class, change main to `Run(..)` your new context class:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new CustomContext());
}
```

And then in your Form1, make sure you have an event, and trigger that event to open new forms (note that in "real" code I'd probably abstract this away, or  most likely let my DI container handle registration, but this shows the point much clearer) :

```
public event EventHandler OpenNewForm;
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //instead of showing a new form, we just raise this event
    if (OpenNewForm != null) OpenNewForm(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

What this does, is let the ApplicationContext manage your open forms, so that closing the first one (or any of them) does not exit the application until you close the *last* one.  Once the last form closes, it exits the app.

Comment: Nope. I have 0 instances of `Application.Run();` appearing in my code.
I have a `newToolStripMenuItem_Click` event wired with the code I posted above.

Comment: Wow, I probably seemed like a bit of an ass there. I realized I was looking at my `Form1.cs` code, and not my `Program.cs`

Comment: I took a look at the code on that link and tried to implement it into my code, but I have 31 errors. `Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct`[4], `Identifier expected`[1], and multiple assembly references missing and variable which apparently don't exist (even though I know they do).
It's a huge help, but unless I can figure out what's wrong, I can't really use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this so many different ways. For a working example of what you want to do, in the Program.cs file change the Main method():

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Form1());
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            GlobalVariables.FormsList = new List<Form1>();  //new
            GlobalVariables.FormsList.Add(frm);             //new
            frm.Show();
            Application.Run();
        }
```

Then on each of your Form1's have a button (or other event) that instantiates a new instance of the form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            GlobalVariables.FormsList.Add(frm);     //new
            frm.Show();
        }
```

Edit: Also add the following code to the FormClosing event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (GlobalVariables.FormsList.Count == 1)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        GlobalVariables.FormsList.RemoveAt(GlobalVariables.FormsList.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is the new GlobalVariables class with the list of Forms to aid form management:

```
   public class GlobalVariables
    {
       public static List<Form1> FormsList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I put that first part in, noob mistake of I was looking at `Form1.cs` wondering why I couldn't find `Application.Run();` anywhere..Anyways, that does exactly what I wanted, thank you.
The only issue is that if I close them all, the application is actually still running.

Comment: I fixed that problem with coding in my exit method.
At the end, I added 
`if (myFormsList == 0) 
 {
    Application.Exit();
 }`

Comment: Nope, I actually didn't fix it. I don't know how to add and remove items from the list. I want it to keep a running tally of how many I have open, so that as long as there is at least one in the least, I can open/close as many forms as I want, and if there are none left in the list, the application closes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are closing the form using it's 'x' button it will not affect the other form.
If you are closing by code you should get the object of that form properly and close it. It would be better if you can keep a catalog of forms so that the management will be easy.

If there are any static variables involved in between try changing that logic without static variables as they are shared across the objects.

Comment: tbh, It makes no difference to my forms if I use the control box or not. I have a method for exiting which I wired `Form1_FormClosing` to. I have tried with and with `exit();` appearing in `Form1_FormClosing` and closing `Form1` (the original) still causes all of the `newForm`s to close as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you can have the form launched by `Application.Run` be a form that just launches other forms, (e.g. your text-editor form).

Something like: (This is just an example to demonstrate the idea.)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += Form1_Shown;
    }

    void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextEditorForm frm2 = new TextEditorForm(this);
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public partial class TextEditorForm : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;

    public TextEditorForm(Form1 frm1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.frm1 = frm1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```